# Regular Expression matching pattern for cc_digits in logstash configuration

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

**msg field data is:**

```
Starting RentalTransactionMessageProcessor cc_digits="1982"
```

**grok matching pattern is:**

```
grok { 
  match => { "msg" => "%{GREEDYDATA:text} cc_digits= %{NUMBER:ccdigits}" } 
}
```

**Rule:**

```
cc_digits should be 4 digits
```

I am checking with the below grokDebugger

http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result

This is not the correct way of writing the matching pattern.Can anybody provide the correct way of writing pattern.

Comment: I am trying with                                                                                           %{GREEDYDATA:text} cc_digits= %{^[0-9]{1,4}$:ccdigits}                couldn't get output...

Comment: Maybe `cc_digits="(?<ccdigits>\d{4})"` or something like that?

Comment: I am giving, `%{GREEDYDATA:text} cc_digits= %(?<ccdigits>\d{4})`  like this but it's not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the quotes.

```
%{GREEDYDATA:text} cc_digits="(?<ccdigits>\d{4})"
```

edit: Remember to escape the quotes, when you are using this pattern.